# Syntax for rpy2 base.with function

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to figure out rpy2 for plotting some graphs. I'd like to be able to use the with function that's part of R's base like it's used it the following R code:

```
with(res, plot(log2FoldChange, -log10(pvalue), pch=20, main="Volcano plot", xlim=c(-2.5,2)))
with(subset(res, padj<.05 ), points(log2FoldChange, -log10(pvalue), pch=20, col="red"))
```

Where res is a dataframe and log2FoldChange and pvalue are columns from that dataframe.

When I import the base package using rpy2's importr I can see that 'with' is in the object by doing:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
dir(base)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2 import robjects
base = importr('base')
base.with(res, robjects.r.plot(log2FoldChange, padj))

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    base.with(res, robjects.r.plot(log2FoldChange, padj))
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Unfortunately, searching for something like 'base.with' has proven intractable. My question: what is the syntax for using 'base.with' in rpy2 python code?

Alternatively, while using 'with' is the most R forward approach to doing this, perhaps there's a more rpy2 friendly approach to this same problem that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python might be getting a conflict with its own `with()` command which requires a space right after it. This is the challenge of interfacing with another language.

Try running the command natively in R syntax wrapped around the `robjects` function. Below I pass Python objects into R's global environment scope.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

ro.globalenv['res'] = res_frompy
ro.globalenv['log2FoldChang'] = log2FoldChang_frompy
ro.globalenv['padj'] = padj_frompy

ro.r('with(res, plot(log2FoldChange, padj))')
```

Comment: +1 because looking at this I think it will definitely work. Testing tomorrow- I'll mark as correct after that as I'm sure it will work. This is actually exactly what I needed to know and I didn't even ask specifically for this.